# How to output a interactive game map from an array in android studios

Tags: java, android

i am complete novice at this, however i cannot find anywhere on the internet how to output a game map from an array. the map has to be interative.

i want to output a game map onto a canvas in a 4x4 grid

public int[] gameBoard1 = {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,4,0};

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier for you to make a 2d array

```
int gameBoard[][] = {
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0}
```

};

and then make a double for loop to read through each row

```
for(int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
//i - index of a row, we have 4 rows so we want to loop through all of them
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        //j - position of an element in that row, every row has 4 positions so we want to
        //loop through all of them on every row
            if(gameBoard[i][j] == 2){
                //draw something at i,j coordinates
                //example:
                canvas.drawRect(j * 50, i * 50, (j + 1) * 50, (i + 1) * 50, new Paint());
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember that 2d array is an array of arrays so when you call it its Board[index of an array][position of element in this array] which means that when you read the coordinates of a 2d array they are inverted. That's why you check for "i,j" and draw at "j,i".

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway that you can apply imaged to the different integers in the array?

Comment: see that "if(fameBoard[i][j] == 2)" ? It means whenever it will find a 2 in your array it will do something. You can then add "else if(gameBoard[i][j] ==1){draw tree}else if(gameBoard[i][j] == 3){draw rock} etc